# How can container (running on the local host) access services running on remote hosts, which are port forwarded to the local host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

Here's a scenario:

- Host (local computer running macOS) has access to the number of services running on various IPs within the `127.1.1.0/24` network range.
- That network is not a real local network, but instead done through `kubectl port-forward` (and maybe some other magic xD). That basically gives host access to the services running in the remote K8s cluster namespace. For context, that is achieved through [Bridge to Kubernetes VSCode extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/overview-bridge-to-kubernetes?view=vs-2019).
- Host can ping or curl any of those services via their respective IPs and ports on the `127.1.1.0/24` network. E.g. `curl 127.1.1.15:9098`

##### How to make a service running **inside the docker container** on the host (local machine) be able to send network requests to any of those port-forwarded remote services with `127.1.1.0/24` IPs?

Any potential solutions appreciated. Thanks.